# Is there a library function to check if a MAC address is multicast?

Tags: python, mac-address

I know that I can use the `netaddr` module to check if an IP address is multicast like so:

```
netaddr.IPAddress("192.168.1.1").is_multicast()
```

Before I go ahead and write my own, is there a comparable function for the various formats of MAC addresses?

For instance:

```
0123.4567.89ab
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness: A "function" to check this is as easy as

```
>>> mac = netaddr.EUI('0123.4567.89ab')
>>> mac_is_multicast = bool(mac.words[0] & 0b01)  # Is LSB set?
```

Similarly, you can check if a MAC address is locally administered with

```
>>> mac = netaddr.EUI('0123.4567.89ab')
>>> mac_is_locally_administered = bool(mac.words[0] & 0b10)  # Is 2nd LSB set?
```

Answer (score 0):

A multicast address has `1` in the least significant bit of the most significant byte. In the hex representation this means the second nibble is odd (because MAC addresses are little-endian). Except that `ffff.ffff.ffff` is the broadcast address.

http://bradhedlund.com/2007/11/21/identifying-ethernet-multicast/

Comment: HI I believe the rule is that it is multicast if 1 in the least-significant bit of the first octet which is straight forward, I just wanted to see if there was a function available already :)

Comment: I think it's the most-significant bit. http://bradhedlund.com/2007/11/21/identifying-ethernet-multicast/